# How to get visible rowindex of aspxgridview on row deleting event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Can anybody help me to get the visible `RowIndex` of the row on `RowDeleting` event of `ASPxGridView` control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [ASPxGridView.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindVisibleIndexByKeyValuetopic) at [ASPxGridView.RowDeleting Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletingtopic)..
First Specify KeyFieldName in gridcontrol properties.

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e) 
 {
   int i = ASPxGridView1.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(e.Keys[ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName]);            

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the **ASPxGridView.RowDeleting** event;

Determine the processed row's key via the **e.Keys[ASPxGridView.KeyFieldName]** dictionary;

Determine the row's visible index via the **ASPxGridView.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue** method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use variable e from the rowdeleting event like this

```
e.visibleIndex
```

Example:

```
With aspxgrid.getDataRow(e.visibleindex)
    'Here you can use your code
End With
```